# which method should be used to install python modules on Linux?

Tags: linux, python

Python modules can usually be installed via, among others,

- `pip`
- the package manager (`yum`, `apt-get`, ...)

Which one is it wiser to use? Can I mix both?

I understand that removal is dependent on the method (installing one way means cleanly uninstalling the same way) but I am more interested in the consequences for the python installation itself (i.e. is the python tree the same no matter the method, or would they clash?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python-specific module management system (`pip`)

- can install modules globally (for all users as `root`) or in your personal user tree,
- offers more modules

General system-level package management systems (`yum`, `apt-get`)

- only install packages globally
- offer fewer modules, but, possibly, better system integration (e.g., they will install the C library which the python module interfaces to automatically).

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a package manager, that is generally the best option.  Package managers will handle dependencies better than `pip`.  You will have fewer packages to choose from, but the package manager should handle updates well.  Systems using `apt-get` can usually be configured to automatically apply updates on a scheduled basis.

`pip` gives you more options, but I would limit its use to your personal user tree.  You may end up with file conflicts with existing packages, if you install packages for all users.